# NestJS TypeORM multiple error handling username and email conflict

Tags: try-catch, nestjs, typeorm

When I am trying to update the username field but this username is already taken. and what should I do to handle my username duplication.

Second problem is trying to update the email field but this email is already taken. and what should I do to handle my email duplication?

when users update their account username and email filed, these two are filed in the same form.
then I throw the specific fields are already used.
my question is how to handle these two cases of error type at the same catch method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First**, NestJs automatically catches all exceptions so no need to explicitly use try-catch block inside nest application unless you are calling a third party API, you can read more about it [here](https://docs.nestjs.com/exception-filters). So, even if you don't use try catch block nest will catch all exceptions thrown by the database.

**Second**, It is still a bad practice because it is better to handle all cases where you expect database to throw error. Since, here you know that database will throw error if duplicate data is inserted then handle those cases before it reaches the database. What I mean by that is:

- Before inserting check whether that data is already present in database or not.
- If it's already there then return a Bad Request exception.
- If not, then insert the data.

*Example: Create new User API.*

```
async createUser(createUserDto: CreateUserDto): Promise<CreateUserRO> {
    const { phone } = createUserDto;
    const existingUser = await this.userRepository.findOne({
      phone,
    });

    if (existingUser) {
      throw new HttpException(
        'Phone number already exists',
        HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
      );
    }

    const user = new User(createUserDto);
    await this.userRepository.persistAndFlush(user);

    return new CreateUserRO(true, user.id);
}
```

Comment: Here I have used Mikro-Orm, please change the database queries according to your ORM.

Comment: Thank you so much, sir, I will follow your code and you gaved me the valuable time I am so happy with this

Comment: ok sir I will change my Typeform Query